# Sendmail Backscatter

Tags: sendmail

I am looking for any advice on how I can stop back scatter on my sendmail servers.  I have looked at the privacy flags and setting a non delivery for anything. I don't think this is a good approach.

I have looked all over but have not be able to find any good documentation on controlling the back scatter issue.

I would appreciate and feed back on stopping this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that backscatter is originating from your mail server, or that you are receiving backscatter from others?

Comment: As Michael suggested any good and short answer requires info about specific kind of backscatter you want to stop.

Comment: Yes the backscatter is originating from my servers.  I should have specified that from the start my apologies.

Comment: What kind of backscatter do you get? Unknown local recipient / mailbox over quota / .....

Comment: It appears the majority of the backscatter is being sent to unknown local recipients.  We are then sending mail back to a legitimate end user because the from address has been spoofed.                                              to=<un_pc@un.org>, delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=32321, relay=unasav1.un.org. dsn=5.0.0, stat=User unknown
r459tUFC028847: r459tUFD028847: return to sender: User unknown

Comment: Why are you bouncing and not simply rejecting the invalid recipients during RCPT TO?